# Convert a canvas to image to export in PDF with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf isn't working

Tags: javascript, laravel, dompdf

I've got an issue. I'm on Laravel and I need to export a HTML page to PDF.
So I'm using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`, I tried to export some datas and images and it works fine.
The fact is I need to export a LineChart Canvas to PDF, so I convert the canvas to image before, it works in my view but not in my PDF.
I use this script to make graphs : https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/charts/

Here's my code :

```
// Controller code
public function pdf($name)
{
    $MyObject = Object::where('name', $name)->first()->toArray();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.object', compact('object'));
    // If I want to return and test with my view I use this line
    return view('pdf.object', compact('object'));
    // If I want to download the pdf I use this line
    return $pdf->download($object['name'] . '.pdf');
}

// HTML Canvas + The script I use
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/mdb.min.js') }}"></script>

// JS Code
var ctxL = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: ["label1","label2","label3"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My first line",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            borderColor : "rgb(66, 40, 124)",
            pointBackgroundColor : "rgb(66, 40, 124)",
            pointHoverBorderColor : "rgb(66, 40, 124)",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            data: [15, 9, 13]
        },
        {
            label: "My second line",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            borderColor : "rgb(120, 60, 135)",
            pointBackgroundColor : "rgb(120, 60, 135)",
            pointHoverBorderColor : "rgb(120, 60, 135)",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            data: [3, 9, 4]
        }
       ]
    },
    options: {
       responsive: true,
       animation: false
    }    
});

var canvas = $('#myChart'); 
var dataURL = canvas.get(0).toDataURL();
var img = $("<img style='width:100%;height:auto;'></img>");
img.attr("src", dataURL);
canvas.replaceWith(img);
```

When I export, my canvas doesn't show up, but in my view, my canvas is an image, is anything I didn't see wrong in my code ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why is your PDF::loadView('pdf.object', compact('object')) different from your test - retrun view('pdf.event', compact('object'))?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, it was an error from me when I copy paste my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to interpret Javascript through php and dompdf, what is not possible, as they will not, cause they don't support that feature.

You should use an other utility that will allow you to execute the javascript that will create the image, like:

- NodeJS + PhantomJS (less complicated solution)
- Selenium (Java) + Facebook webdriver
- wkhtmltopdf or wkhtmltoimage (have problems with canvas plugins rendring)
- Use a native php library for charts

Those utilities will allow you to render your page and get the image you want to export to PDF, you can even get the PDF directly from some of theme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try tonight and tell you if it works for me !

Comment: Hi. I personnaly used html2canvas + jsPDF to do this from front-end.

Comment: Do you have a name of native php library for charts to advise me ?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I used this one a long time ago,  but you can google it to find what is there as it could exist something better. http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for convert canvas into a PDF file print angular(typescript)

```
    downloadCanvas(){
            this.chart =document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL("Image/jpg");
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = this.chart;
            this.dev.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<img src="'+img.src+'">' );
    }
}
```